# Converting list of lists to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of strings like the following

```
string_list = ['''{"no" : 1, "name": "John Doe", "address": "123, Einstein St, SA, 28372"}''', '''{'no" : 1, "name": "John Denver", "address": "454, BohrSt, SA, 64584"}''']
```

I am trying to convert each string in the list into a dictionary and append it to a dictionary.

```
import json
newdict = {}
for string in string_list:
    new = json.loads(string)
    newdict.update(new)
```

but it is producing an error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But if I do,

```
new = json.loads(string_list[1])
```

It works. And gives the type of `new` as `<class 'dict'>`. How can I solve this?

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries, not strings. What exactly do you want to do,  maybe provide some sample output so we can understand how to help you. Also what is it you want json for?

Comment: Did you look to see what `string` was?  And why maybe that wasn't the best name for that variable?

Comment: @RolvApneseth they are actually strings. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I see, running your code also gives me this error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`, however I'm assuming that's just a typo in `string_list`, the second string has `'no"`, just change the single quote to a double and your code doesn't error out. However it will only do one of the strings (effectively) since they both have the same keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one maybe you need

- use `json.loads` to convert the element of `string_list` to dict
- convert list of lists to dictionary of dictionaries by `dict comprehension`

## code:

```
import json
string_list = ['{"no" : 1, "name": "John Doe", "address": "123, Einstein St, SA, 28372"}', '{"no" : 1, "name": "John Doe", "address": "123, Einstein St, SA, 28372"}']
print({idx:json.loads(data) for idx,data in enumerate(string_list)})
```

## result:

```
{
    0: {"no": 1, "name": "John Doe", "address": "123, Einstein St, SA, 28372"},
    1: {"no": 1, "name": "John Doe", "address": "123, Einstein St, SA, 28372"},
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. It is the list of strings.

Comment: @Vance Pyton the `string_list` in the question may have quote problem, if you want to quote a string contain `"`, you need to use `'`.

Comment: @Vance Pyton I ran your code with python 3.7.7 but it didn't produce any error, maybe the version problem?